# Ajax Is getting errors when I've changed to using SSL

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl, https

I recently got an SSL cerificate on my web server, and suddenly all of the AJAX requests are failing.

I have tried changing the code to use https:// and // but both aren't working. This is really annoying, and I can see that it's being blocked as shown in the attached image.

The error shown is:

> 'Loading mixed (insecure) active content
>   "http://pximg.xyz/api/backup_site/?api_key=&mode=" on a secure page'

*(removed the API key and stuff)*

I've looked into this, and it's because the SSL isn't  being forced, resulting in the ajax attempting to go to http instead. This gets blocked by Firefox.

The Ajax call that I'm making is:

```
function backupSite() {
    console.log("Backing up Site");
    $.get( "https://pximg.xyz/api/backup_site",
    { api_key: '', mode: '' })
    .done(function(data) {
        var newData = data.split('"');
        alert('Completed');
    });
}
```

I've tried changing my code, redirects, and hardcoding it to use HTTPS, but none of these have worked so far. Is it possible to get some help on how I can get this working?

Extra Information:

- Server Host  - Hostinger, Premium
- Server Soft  - Apache 2.4.10 (according to Hostinger)
- PHP Version  - 5.5
- SSL Provider - Comodo

Kind Regards,
PXgamer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add trailing slash to your url `https://pximg.xyz/api/backup_site/`
and [check http headers](http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php) for your request to make sure that no any redirects happening.

Comment: It is getting a 301, just going to try something.

Comment: @PXgamer `301` to where? same protocol and location or not?

Comment: Hahaha. Thank you so so much! I'd missed out the trailing slash, and so it was redirecting to use the / as it's a directory.

Comment: @PXgamer np, just get the same issue days ago with CloudFlare SSL